# As3: Button only working in certain locations?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, movieclip

I really don't know how to explain this problem. I'm really stumped as to what is causing it.
Here is the code:

```
var abutton:AButton = new AButton; //Where AButton is a button defined in my library
addChildAt(abutton, numChildren);
abutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, attack);
```

It doesn't want to work when certain movie clips are underneath it, but I don't want to make it more complicated by switching to another screen. Is it possible to make the button work with movieclips underneath?

Comment: `addChildAt(abutton, numChildren);` is the same as `addChild(abutton);`

Comment: Just make sure your button has a hit area that fills in all the negative space.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "certain movieclips"? What do you mean by not working? The `CLICK` event isn't firing? Normally if a click isn't working on a button, it means that something else it trapping the mouse click *above* your button. This can be another `Sprite`, `MovieClip` or `TextField`.

Add a click listener to the stage, and have it print out `target` and `currentTarget`. Then, when you button doesn't work, the stage listener will still fire and you'll be able to see the object that's blocking your button.

Comment: This should more be a comment tha n an answer.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship good point - I just hate the lack of formatting in comments. It makes it hard to read a comment of any length. Plus, this lets me update my answer if he does what I ask of him ;)

Comment: Basically what I have is an array of tiles (MovieClip) underneath the button. The mouse over button thing is not working on half of the button. In an attempt to fix it I removed all the tiles before displaying the button. Still only half the button works. It only works in the upper left corner of the screen as well.

Comment: if you add nothing but the button does it work? does the button have a textfield or internal clip that could be stealing focus? if so, try setting mouseChildren to false on your button or selectable to false on the textfield

Comment: also, if it's only working in the upper left corner of the screen, do you have a sprite or something with alpha 0 covering part of the stage? what's the target on the stage click listener?